# MS Graph GET /me/drive returns zeros for quota information

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Did something change this week regarding quota for business accounts?
Suddenly `GET /me/drive` returns all zeros for quota for all accounts where driveType is "business":

```
    "quota":{"deleted":0,"remaining":0,"total":0,"used":0}}
```

Is there some other way we're supposed to find out how much free space is available?

Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this same thing, which was working fine. Adding the scope Sites.Read.All fixed it for me.